# how can i change the visibility of a button when the user modyfies the data inside recyclerview?

Tags: android-fragments, button, kotlin, android-recyclerview, visibility

I need to change the visibility of a button deppending on a recycler's view content, when it changes it must become visible otherwise it has to remain invisible

I've tried with interfaces, callback and "onactivityresult" to add a changelistener to the recyclerview, with the interface I can access a method from the parent class but I cant reach the view's it returns me nulls

the structure is the following:

> parent class(viewpager, with button that needs to change it's visibility)
>   child class(recyclerview)
>   adapter(Call to API service, listener to button and Edittext, "I need to modify it from here")

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps if you want to send data from child class to parent class.

You have to create a custom listener.

```
public interface HideButton{
  void hideButton();
}
```

now create a instance of this interface in child class or adapter class

```
HideButton hideButtonListener;
```

and create a setter in the adapter class,

```
public void setButtonHideListener(HideButton listener){
     this.hideButtonListener = listener;
}
```

and call this setter from parent class by the adapter reference e.g

```
adapter.setButtonHideListener(new HideButton(){
    void hideButton(){
    //here you change the visibility of the button in parent class
    }
});
```

one more step. Now when you call an api in adapter and receive the response, you call this code

```
if(hideButtonListener != null){
   hideButtonListener.hideButton();
}
```

Comment: Now parent will listen on this listener, whenever the child class calls it. parent will receive it and you can perform your action. e.g hide button or show button. etc..